# HSTS header (through .htaccess) not being served on Wordpress pages

Tags: .htaccess, hsts

My Wordpress website had HSTS headers set up through .htaccess file and it was working fine, until at some point it stopped sending the header, and I don't know when or why (I've since been configuring and updating my VPS server, so everything is possible). The thing is, it still works if I add the header directly to httpd.conf file, just not when I try to do it on site by site basis through .htaccess file. Redirects, passwords and other things still work using .htaccess btw...

Furthermore, a blank test html page I created still sends the HSTS header. So what could be overwritting the HSTS rule when it comes to serving wordpress PHP pages? Because clearly the httaccess code is still correct, since html page serves it as intended.

This is the code I use:

```
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload" env=HTTPS
```

I repeat, this same code works if I edit the Apache config file... and it still works through .htaccess when I serve blank html files. There must be an easy explanation for this? Thanks!

UPDATE on MrWhite's request. Here is the content of my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload" env=HTTPS

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

<files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 401 default
ErrorDocument 403 Denied

<FilesMatch “wp-login.php”=””>
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Private area. Failed attempt IPs logged and reported."
AuthUserFile "/home/censoredusername/.htpasswds/public_html/wp-admin/passwd"
Require valid-user
</FilesMatch>

<Files admin-ajax.php>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Satisfy any
</Files>

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Wordfence WAF
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>

# END Wordfence WAF
```

Here are the redirects and server responses that come with html and php outside the WordPress (without htaccess specified env var). They are missing the www redirect because that one was done by WordPress so far. Will include it in htaccess from now on.

PHP:

```
censored.com/test.php

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Thu, 03 Dec 2020 13:39:33 GMT
Server: Apache
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block;
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Location: https://censored.com/test.php
Content-Length: 243
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

https://censored.com/test.php

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 03 Dec 2020 13:39:36 GMT
Server: Apache
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block;
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Vary: User-Agent
Content-Length: 11
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

HTML:

```
censored.com/test.html

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Thu, 03 Dec 2020 13:42:39 GMT
Server: Apache
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block;
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Location: https://censored.com/test.html
Content-Length: 244
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

https://censored.com/test.html

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 03 Dec 2020 13:42:41 GMT
Server: Apache
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block;
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Last-Modified: Wed, 02 Dec 2020 12:45:56 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 120
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: Where are you setting the `HTTPS` environment variable?

Comment: "it still works if I add the header directly to httpd.conf file" - Is that using the _exact_ directive you have posted above? Although it should not include the `env=` argument (since you are only setting this in the vHost for port 443 I assume).

Comment: Yes, that is using the exact same directive, including the env=https argument, since I don't really know better I guess. I am on WHM/CPanel CentOS 7 VPS, so I did not have to set much by hand to have it working. Until it stopped that is :/

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload" env=HTTPS
> ```

You've not stated where you are setting the `HTTPS` *environment* variable (this isn't something that is set by default; it's not the same as the `HTTPS` server variable of the same name).

However, for this to work with WordPress "virtual" URLs that are rewritten by the WP front-controller then (on Apache) you will need to check for the `REDIRECT_HTTPS` env var, since the `HTTPS` env var is renamed after the request is internally rewritten to the WP front-controller.

For example:

```
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload" env=REDIRECT_HTTPS
```

Comment: MrWhite, thank you so much for your time! Solely changing my code to yours did not fix the problem. My website is still not sending the HSTS header on WP php pages.    

It probably doesn't matter, but my .htaccess has a https redirect set up to redirect all http traffic straight to https, then WP redirects it once again to www (canonical url) to fulfill the HSTS preload requirement of two redirects (unfortunately).    

The https redirect is set up like this:  
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Comment: Please edit your question to include the contents of your `.htaccess` file. Where is the `HTTPS` env var being set? "then WP redirects it once again to www" - why not perform this redirect in `.htaccess` as well?

Comment: Also try removing the `env=` argument altogether. This should set it unconditionally on all requests (including HTTP). This shouldn't be a violation of HSTS preload (although may trigger a warning - since it's "unnecessary"). It's certainly not a violation of [HSTS](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6797). When compliant browsers receive this header over plain HTTP they should simply ignore it.

Comment: I have edited my question to include the .htaccess. As far as not performing the www redirect in .htaccess as well, Wordpress was already doing it by default so I didn't bother with it. But I assume it's best done right away by Apache and I should change it, correct? I will give your other suggestions a try if there are no red flags in the htaccess file I posted.

Comment: UPDATE: If I remove the ENV var, it sends the HSTS header, but only on the first redirect (http to https), once at https the header is no longer present on the way to www. And if I include the ENV var, it is not sent at all. So I guess you might be right about the env var not being set properly being the culprit, unfortunately this is outside the scope of my knowledge. What should I Google to fix this / understand it better? Thanks!

Comment: To clarify, the header is not present on _any_ response from WordPress? If you try creating a `file.php` (as opposed to `.html`) outside of WP with a simple `echo 'Hello World';` - is the header set on this response? AFAIK it's not possible for PHP/WordPress to "unset" this header. Is your site functioning OK with "pretty URLs" when accessed over HTTPS? You're not using a CDN or front-end proxy?

Comment: I have updated the initial post to show you the difference between responses. And yes, HTML sends the header, PHP does not. BTW, what would the best way to double redirect through htaccess be? I've seen several ways and was wondering if it matters which way it's done. Is certain code more taxing on the server or slower than the other? Or it doesn't matter as long as it gets the 301 redirect done? Either way, I want both redirects to be done by Apache instead of half and half as is now. I assume that should make it a bit faster as well. Thanks man, I really appreciate your time and effort!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently WordPress created redirects disregard the .htaccess rules / headers, and since the www redirect was done by WordPress, proper headers were not sent. I could swear it worked at some point, but maybe I added that redirect afterwards and forgot. Thanks to MrWhite for pointing out that all redirects are better off being done by Apache. I moved the www redirect over to htaccess and now everything works fine yet again.

I wanted to accept MrWhite's comment "why not perform this redirect in .htaccess as well? – MrWhite Dec 2" as the answer, but apparently that is not possible with comments, only replies? If you want, you can post the above solution as an answer as you deserve the credit for it. Thanks!